# cannot get value of inputs wrapped by ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I can not get value of input wrapped by ng-if
this is html code

```
<div ng-controller="Home">
    <form ng-submit="startChat(visitor)" >
        <div class="lkv_getting">
            <div ng-if="formsetting.name == true">
                <input required ng-class="lkv_name_class" ng-model="visitor.name" id="lkv_name" name="lkv_name" type="text" class="lkv_input" placeholder="Nhập họ tên" />
            </div>                
            <textarea required maxlength="100" placeholder="Gõ tin nhắn!!" ng-model="visitor.msg" id="message_input" name="lkv_message_input"></textarea>
            <button class="lkv_button" type="submit" id="lkv_start" title="Message">Bắt đầu</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and controller

```
$scope.startChat = function (visitor) {        

    var user = visitor.name; // the value is undefine
    var msg = visitor.msg; // but this one has value
};
```

Any one can help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ng-if the DOM elements won't get rendered if formsetting.name ever equals false.  That means you won't be able to get your input values back since they won't be rendered to the DOM.  Check to see that formsetting.name is indeed true or initialized to true in your controller if that makes sense for you.  If formsetting.name can change values you probably want to use ng-show instead.  Using ng-show draws the elements to the DOM but hides them so you can still access them.

Comment: can you give me snippet code for this situation. thanks

Comment: Can formsetting.name ever change from true to false? Or will it always remain the same value once the controller is loaded? Can you show me how formsetting.name is getting set in your controller?

Comment: in my case `formsetting.name` is  true and DOM elements is showed. sorry for my Englisg

Comment: Put this at the top of your controller and see what happens: $scope.visitor = {};

Comment: if I put the input outside ng-if, I can get its value (like the textarea ) but inside ng-if I can not even formsetting.name is true or false

Comment: `Put this at the top of your controller` you mean put outside `$scope.startChat = function (visitor) {` ?

Comment: fyi, you can change ng-if to ng-if="formsetting.name", no need to compare to true.  That won't fix your issue but it's less code.

Comment: Hey first value is obviously undefined ,you didn't assign any value to it.

Comment: thank you very much, I put `$scope.visitor = {}` at the top of my controller. and it work like a charm. But I dont know how visitor.msg is working but visitor.name is not

Comment: its because you didn't assign any value to visitor.name

Comment: because in textfield you provide value to it

Comment: Suppose i have two things A and B under C.If i assign value to C.B and hide C.A how can i get the value inside C.A ..??

Comment: @squiroid this issue just appear when the input is put inside ng-if. anyway I have solved my problem, thank all of you